# How does calling C or C++ from python work?

Tags: python, c++, c, language-binding

There are multiple questions about "how to" call C C++ code from Python. But I would like to understand what exactly happens when this is done and what are the performance concerns. What is the theory underneath? Some questions I hope to get answered by understanding the principle are:

When considering data (especially large data) being processed (e.g. 2GB) which needs to be passed from python to C / C++ and then back. How are the data transferred from python to C when function is called? How is the result transferred back after function ends? Is everything done in memory or are UNIX/TCP sockets or files used to transfer the data? Is there some translation and copying done (e.g. to convert data types), do I need 2GB memory for holding data in python and additional +-2GB memory to have a C version of the data that is passed to C function? Do the C code and Python code run in different processes?

Comment: 2GB of data to transfer. Files may be the better option.

Comment: Depends on how exactly you go about it. Potentially the data can be shared in the same process without copying if you use the ctypes Python module to call C/C++ code in a shared library or DLL. You could also embed the Python interpreter in your C/C++ application and share it using a Python extension module. Or you could do it like you described with separate processes and sockets if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call between C, C++, Python, and a bunch of other languages without spawning a separate process or copying much of anything.

In Python basically everything is reference-counted, so if you want to use a Python object in C++ you can simply use the same reference count to manage its lifetime (e.g. to avoid copying it even if Python decides it doesn't need the object anymore).  If you want the reverse, you may need to use a C++ `std::shared_ptr` or similar to hold your objects in C++, so that Python can also reference them.

In some cases things are even simpler than this, such as if you have a pure function in C or C++ which takes some values from Python and returns a result with no side effects and no storing of the inputs.  In such a case, you certainly do not need to copy anything, because you can read the Python values directly and the Python interpreter will not be running while your C or C++ code is running (because they are all in a single thread).

There is an extensive Python (and NumPy, by the way) C API for this, plus the excellent Boost.Python for C++ integration including smart pointers.

Comment: I thought that Python data is in a different format and C can not work with it directly. Or is the python using same data types? Is the C directly accessing the memory addresses where python saved the data and can read data without any translation? I wonder in what way is the C API called. The only way I called APIs between different languages before was using Http.

Comment: It's maybe worthwhile to add that the "default" Python, CPython, is implemented in C. Because of that, there isn't really a different language somewhere. Libraries like `numpy` or the ones created by `Boost.Python` simply connect with Python on the C level from the beginning. Check e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html for the basics.

Comment: The most popular implementations of Python are *written* in C in the first place, so of course C can use Python data structures.  There are C APIs to deal with the Python data types like list and dict.  For example, if you get a pointer in C to a list from Python, you can use the C API described here: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html